# Limiting bandwidth of workstations in MS Forefront TMG

Tags: cache, bandwidth-control, microsoft-forefront, microsoft-forefront-2010, microsoft-ftmg-2010

We have configured Microsoft forefront TMG 2010 Enterprise as the cache server which provides internet access for all computers in our department.

Is there any way to limit download speed per host/user by configuring forefront TMG?

I have found a tool called [Bandwidth Splitter](http://www.bsplitter.com/) but it is expensive ($499 for 50 clients!) and we would like to avoid it.

It is a shame for Microsoft if its 6 thousands dollar software does not provide this feature, but squid does! (with leaky buckets)

**Note:** We (sadly?) have to use forefront TMG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no bandwidth management built-in TMG 2010 as of SP1.

Comment: We failed to avoid Bandwidth Splitter. We bought it :-|. anyway, I am interested in programming for TMG 2010. How can I write such extensions for TMG?

Comment: There's a TMG SDK available on msdn.microsoft.com (and a downloadable copy too) for making Application Filters and Web Filters.